# Java error on build: Unable to write output

Tags: java, spring, junit, ant

I'm trying to build my project but it's not working. My source build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Optin" default="package" basedir=".">

<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="test-lib">
    <fileset dir="test-lib">
        <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Cleans previous builds -->
<target name="clean">

    <echo message="Cleaning older builds..."/>

    <!-- Cleans the work folder -->
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="work" includes="**/*"/>
        <fileset dir="build" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>

</target>

<!-- Compiles the classes -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean">

    <echo message="Compiling..."/>

    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" compiler="javac1.7" target="1.7">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>

    <mkdir dir="build/tests"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="tests" destdir="build/tests" compiler="javac1.7" target="1.7">
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        <classpath refid="test-lib" />
    </javac>

</target>

<!-- Run junit tests -->
<target name="tests" depends="compile">

    <echo message="Running tests..."/>

    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="true">

        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        <classpath refid="test-lib" />

        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="build/classes"/>
            <pathelement location="build/tests"/>
        </classpath>

        <formatter type="xml" />
        <formatter type="plain" />

        <batchtest todir="test-report">
            <fileset dir="tests">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>

    </junit>

</target>

<!-- Prepares the package to go -->
<target name="package" depends="tests">
    <echo message="Packing..."/>

    <!-- Gets the timestamp of this build -->
    <tstamp>
        <format property="timestamp" pattern="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"/>
    </tstamp>

    <input message="Please select the target environment:" addproperty="destenv" defaultvalue="dev" validargs="dev,fqa"/>

    <!-- Creates the jar -->
    <mkdir dir="work/bin"/>
    <jar destfile="work/bin/optin.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.vilt.tim.optin.App"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <!-- Creates the directory structure -->
    <mkdir dir="work/conf"/>
    <mkdir dir="work/lib"/>
    <mkdir dir="work/logs"/>
    <mkdir dir="work/input"/>
    <mkdir dir="work/output"/>

    <!-- Copies the additional resources -->
    <copy todir="work">
        <fileset dir="resources/pack">
            <include name="*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copies the related properties -->
    <copy todir="work/conf">
        <fileset dir="properties/${destenv}">
            <include name="*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="work/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Creates the package -->
    <zip destfile="package/${timestamp}_optin_build.zip" basedir="work" update="false" level="9"/>

    <!-- Clean everything at the end -->
    <antcall target="clean"></antcall>

</target>
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build.xml
clean:
 [echo] Cleaning older builds...
compile:
 [echo] Compiling...
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build\classes
[javac] Compiling 11 source files to     C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build\classes
[javac] C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\lib\spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar(org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'Repeatable': class file for java.lang.annotation.Repeatable not found
[javac] 1 warning
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build\tests
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build\tests
tests:
 [echo] Running tests...
 [junit] Running com.vilt.tim.optin.AppTest

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\renato.silva\git\optin\build.xml:52: Unable to write output

 Total time: 1 second
```

But when I run the test class individually it works fine. I'm using Spring annotations:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import    org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AppTest {  

@Test
public void test(){

    Assert.assertTrue(true);

     }

}
```

What am I missing?

PS: when I comment the target tests lines the build works, but when I run `java -jar` the following error occurs:

> Error: Could not find or load main class .

I'm not sure if the errors are related.

Answer (score 2):

The following line was missing:

```
<mkdir dir="test-report"/>
```

Now works perfectly!